# Same view, different hex codes. Which one is true?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, jpg, color-spaces, web-safe, hex

I'm working on Yandex social media covers and the problem is the yellow. First of all, this is my color profile (same with the project owner)

[image]

And the code given to me is #fedc4a. But when I export file via save for web and open it in photoshop, with eyedropper it looks #ffdc4a.

There is no difference while comparing them but code looks false. What's the problem?

I'm adding a psd which shows the colors (i can't post it as jpg because it changes the values again).

https://www.dropbox.com/s/7mlalqesliioxjo/differences.psd?dl=0

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Working space set to Monitor == **bad**. Set it to your *actual* "working space". For photography that would be your camera's space, for web design that would be sRGB. Your monitor's profile is automatically compensated when drawing to screen, it doesn't need to be in your workflow at all.

Answer (score 3):

You are seeing some kind of rounding problem. In hex notation, ff means 255 and fe means 254. The difference can't be seen by a human eye.

I also notice that you have turned off color management in PS. While this may work in some cases, for instance when you want to match an exact color in a jpg with the same color value set in CSS/HTML, it may create problems when dealing with color managed files, like photographs. I suggest setting up your color management to the default SWOP or perhaps ISO Coated settings and discarding color profiles on a file per file basis.

It is actually not possible to "disable" color management, as rgb values in files do not represent specific colors without an appropriate color profile (e.g. sRGB).

Best regards, 
Henning

Comment: This is almost what I'm thinking. Thanks for your reply Herrklaseen!